# SQLite query to delete from multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I use a query to retrieve a list of tables with a specific column name:

```
select name from sqlite_master where type='table' and sql like '%unique_col_id%';
```

So, it return a list of table names for example, table_1, table_2, table_3..

I would like to delete all rows in the above tables with unique_col_id equal to specific value:

```
DELETE FROM table_1 where unique_col_id=3;
DELETE FROM table_2 where unique_col_id=3;
DELETE FROM table_3 where unique_col_id=3;
```

Is there a way to delete all table in one query? I mean to integrate both queries (search the table and delete all of them with unique_col_id=3...)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do it in one query? Is this something that could be solved with transactions or [triggers](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)?

Comment: I'm using PHP as a server and the performance is very bad if I'm trying to delete multiple table with multiple queries.

Comment: This is what we call an XY problem. Your problem is X (performance) but you've asked about Y (your attempt at a solution to X which might not be a solution and might make things worse). There's a lot of things which could be affecting your performance. Multiple, simple queries probably isn't the problem, it's probably searching on unindexed columns. Instead, you should ask about your performance problem, probably in a new question. Come up with minimal code that demonstrates the problem, and be sure to show your SQL schema.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While I'm sure there is some way you can do all that in one statement, it's better to either use [transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) and/or [triggers](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

A transaction lets you group a bunch of statements together so that nothing is saved until they all run. No other process will see your changes until the transaction is complete. If there's an error or your process dies in the middle of a transaction, all changes are thrown out. This avoids a whole host of issues. Using transactions lets you use simple statements rather than trying to smash everything together into an unmaintainable mess.

```
begin;
DELETE FROM table_1 where unique_col_id=3;
DELETE FROM table_2 where unique_col_id=3;
DELETE FROM table_3 where unique_col_id=3;
commit;
```

Compliment this with triggers. This lets the database automatically take actions when something happens, like when you delete a column from one table it can delete related information from other tables. The most typical way to do this is to set [`ON DELETE CASCADE` on your foreign keys](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions).

```
# This is necessary in SQLite else foreign keys will be ignored
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys = on;

# Make two tables with a relationship and set it ON DELETE CASCADE
sqlite> create table addresses ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, address TEXT, person REFERENCES people(id) ON DELETE CASCADE );
sqlite> create table people ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT );

# Add a row with a relationship.
sqlite> insert into people (name) VALUES ("Foo Bar");
sqlite> select * from people;
1|Foo Bar
sqlite> insert into addresses (address, person) VALUES ("123 Foo St", 1);
sqlite> select * from people join addresses on addresses.person = people.id;
1|Foo Bar|1|123 Foo St|1

# Delete the parent row and the child (address) is also deleted.
sqlite> delete from people where id = 1;
sqlite> select * from people;
sqlite> select * from addresses;
```

This is much more robust.  People making changes to your database don't need to know all the details, the database takes care of it for them.

Comment: Thanks, Transactions is goos enough for me

Answer (score 0):

**Method to delete all tables**

```
 public void dropAllTables() {
            // query to obtain the names of all tables in your database
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
            List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();

            // iterate over the result set, adding every table name to a list
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                tables.add(c.getString(0));
            }

           // call DROP TABLE on every table name
            for (String table : tables) {
                String dropQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table;
                db.execSQL(dropQuery);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need here to make a transaction query like this below :

```
begin transaction 
delete from fkTable where fk = @id delete from pkTable where pk = @id 
commit
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! I believe your answer is being downvoted for two reasons. First, that doesn't appear to be valid SQL; are you missing a semicolon? Second, code only answers are discouraged; we prefer answers to come with explanations so people can learn why they do things, not just cut & paste code.

Comment: It's a bit confuse, can you explain better your answer to the issue?