# Delete Multiple Table In single SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room

I am using Room Database over SQlite and Live Data in my android application. I need to delete whole table data not database so I am going to delete table in separate Query like:

`DELETE From Table_name`

But I want to delete multiple tables data not drop in single Query not all tables. So please give me an appropriate solution.

Comment: Use DELETE to delete rows from a table. Use DROP to drop a table.

Comment: Please give us the details of the tables involved.  Generally, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397417/sqlite-query-to-delete-multiple-tables).

Comment: @Tim  i want to delete tables like t1,t2,t3 only not all tables from database, which contains more tables then these three  through single Sql Query.

Comment: @jarlh i know DELETE And DROP but i want to know how to delete more than one table in single query.

Comment: @singh.indolia, don't forget the _from_ word. You want to delete _from_ more than one table.

Comment: @singh.indolia you keep saying *delete* and *tables* in the same sentence. Either you want to *delete rows* from multiple tables or *drop multiple tables*. Which is it? In any case you can't affect multiple tables with a single data definition statement like DROP. You can include many such statements in a single batch/script though.

Comment: What delete means  in sql terminology. it is  delete data from table like: delete from table_name. i am not truncating or drop a table