# Delete from a SQL Table using a couple JOINs

Tags: sql, sqlite

There are 4 Tables:

```
Users: id,name
Albums: id,user_id
Pictures: id,picture_name,album_id
Tags: picture_id , user_id
```

I need to write 2 commands: 
- a command which deletes a picture by its name -
which means, removing it from the "Tags" table and from the "Pictures" table.
- a command which adds a tag to a picture of a User.

I have tried so far those two commands (which don't seem to work):

Deleting from the tags table:

```
DELETE FROM Tags
 JOIN Albums
 ON Users.id=Albums.user_id  
 JOIN PICTURES
 ON Pictures.album_id = Albums.id  
WHERE Pictures.name LIKE "pic_name.png" ;
```

Deleting from the pictures table:

```
DELETE FROM Pictures
WHERE Pictures.name LIKE "pic_name.png" ;
```

Adding a tag of " user1 " on picture "pic_name2.png" to the Tags table:

```
INSERT INTO Tags (user_id,picture_id) SELECT Users.id, Pictures.id FROM Albums JOIN Users ON Users.id=Albums.user_id  JOIN PICTURES ON Pictures.album_id = Albums.id  WHERE Users.name LIKE "user1" and Pictures.name= "pic_name2.png";
```

please help me write those queries correctly ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397417/sqlite-query-to-delete-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

```
delete from Tags
 where user_id in
( select user_id from Albums
  JOIN PICTURES
  ON PICTURES.album_id = Albums.id  
  WHERE Pictures.name LIKE '%pic_name.png%'
)
```

2nd query

```
DELETE FROM Pictures
WHERE Pictures.name LIKE '%pic_name.png%'
```

and 3rd query only need change where

```
WHERE Users.name ='user1' and Pictures.name= 'pic_name2.png'
```

Comment: thanks! it's only the first query tho.. do you mean that the rest of my queries are actually right??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join any tables to delete the rows:

```
delete from tags
where picture_id = (
  select id from pictures
  where picture_name = 'pic_name.png' 
);

delete from pictures
where picture_name = 'pic_name.png';
```

The tables `users` and `pictures` cannot and do not need to be joined. 
You can insert a new row like this:

```
insert into tags (user_id, picture_id) values
(
  (select id from users where name = 'user1'), 
  (select id from pictures where picture_name = 'pic_name2.png')
);
```

As you can see I changed all `like` to `=` because this is what you need in this case. 
See more [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/)